# is there any way to achieve full parent width inside a div even if the parent has padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, apexcharts

i have a card element here inside this card as you can see i have 2headings and one apex chart. currently the chart also look smaller because of the padding i set on the parent div. i want to make this chart look like a background image ( but i can't set it as background because it's not an SVG ). and see the second image to understand what i want to achieve!

[image: currently what i have]

**i want the output like this!** currently i achieve this by making the chart in **a absolute position and tweaking the bottom and left properties little by little,** is there any cleaner way to implement this?

[image: what i need to achieve]

Comment: Show your (relevant, "*[mcve]*") HTML and CSS; otherwise we can only make guesses (wasting your time and ours) as to what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the parent element has `padding: 20px`. On the child element you can do:

```
.child{
  width: calc(100% + 20px * 2);
  transform: translateX(calc(-1 * 20px));
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Not sure thats neccessarily "cleaner" though

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative margin to offset the padding

```css
.parent {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto
}

.child {
  background: green;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```